# AWK or bash script to get the rows of a file where the specific column is equal to the given variable

Tags: unix, awk

In a for loop, where variable **x** is changing, I  need to get the rows of the **input.txt** that have the 2nd column equals to variable **x**.

```
awk '{if ($2 == "ABC-0361-T00"){print}}' input.txt
```

works. However, when I define it in a variable, it does not work.

```
x="ABC-0361-T00"
awk '{if ($2 == $x){print}}' input.txt
awk '{if ($2 == "$x"){print}}' input.txt
```

What am I missing?

Comment: IMHO, it looks like you want to pass a shell variable to awk program(from your samples I understand it), if this is the case attached link to question will help you, thank you.

Comment: Where is the ink?

Comment: Its attached in your question, let me post it here as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: No, unfortunately  I could not get an answer.

Comment: You should use your command like `awk -v val="$x"  '{if ($2 == val){print}}' input.txt` like this you need to create an awk variable from shell variable and then use it in your program

Comment: Yes, now it flies :) Thanks :)